# AndroidX DataStore: Multiple Profiles

Tags: android, android-jetpack, androidx, android-jetpack-datastore

In my app I'm using AndroidX DataStore to save preferences.

To do this, I followed the documentation and added a Context property at file-level like this:

```
val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "preferences")
```

Now I want to dynamically access a DataStore with a different name, say "preferences_1" or "preferences_2", depending on a selected profile id.

I retrieve the profile id in my Activity `onCreate` function and it stays the same for the whole lifetime of the activity.

How can I dynamically set the DataStore instance?